# gpiozero Button.when_pressed

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I'm learning python and gpio using the examples here:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html

I wanted to extend the code to more than one button and pass a parameter to a function (for example the button number). The code works for both buttons when I don't pass a parameter, but doesn't when I pass one. I'm sure it's [related to the note here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button), but I don't know how to get around that. Here's the code that doesn't work, in fact it prints Hello! 1 then Hello! 2 without any buttons being pressed then does nothing when either button is pressed, but prints Goodbye! when either button is released. How do I fix the code to call the function with a parameter when either button is pressed? Thank you.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello(button_number):
    print("Hello!", button_number)

def say_goodbye():
    print("Goodbye!")

button1 = Button(2)
button2 = Button(3)

button1.when_pressed = say_hello(1)
button1.when_released = say_goodbye
button2.when_pressed = say_hello(2)
button2.when_released = say_goodbye

pause()
```

Code that works based on the answer below:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello(button_number):
    if button_number == 1:
        return lambda: print("Hello, Button 1!")
    if button_number == 2:
        return lambda: print("Hello, Button 2!")

def say_goodbye():
    print("Goodbye!")

button1 = Button(2)
button2 = Button(3)

button1.when_pressed = say_hello(1)
button1.when_released = say_goodbye
button2.when_pressed = say_hello(2)
button2.when_released = say_goodbye

pause()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when_pressed wants a reference to a function, maybe something like

```
def say_hello(x):
    if(x == 1):
        return lambda: print("Pressed 1")
```

... and so on for other cases.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'll have to go learn about lambdas now and why that worked and mine didn't.

Comment: For anyone else coming here: this answer works but it is not a very good way to write python :)

Dirk's answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use parameters with callback functions. See e.g. [Documentation for button.when_pressed](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_pressed)

> This can be set to a function which accepts no (mandatory) parameters,
>   or a Python function which accepts a single mandatory parameter (with
>   as many optional parameters as you like). If the function accepts a
>   single mandatory parameter, the device that activated will be passed
>   as that parameter.

So the following code

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello(button):
    print(button.pin)

def say_goodbye():
    print("Goodbye!")

button1 = Button(20)
button2 = Button(21)

button1.when_pressed = say_hello
button1.when_released = say_goodbye
button2.when_pressed = say_hello
button2.when_released = say_goodbye

pause()
```

results in

```
GPIO20
Goodbye!
GPIO21
Goodbye!
```

(when pressing the appropriate buttons, of course)

So the button instance is always the first parameter. If you want to use additional parameters you can set the button instance manually:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello(button, text = ""):
    print(text + str(button.pin.number))

def say_goodbye():
    print("Goodbye!")

button1 = Button(20)
button2 = Button(21)

button1.when_pressed = say_hello
button1.when_released = say_goodbye
button2.when_pressed = say_hello(button2, text = "Button 2 connected to ")
button2.when_released = say_goodbye

pause()
```

Pressing button 2 will result in

```
Button 2 connected to 21
```

Comment: Works as expected. You can even subclass the Button to pass any parameters for the callback using this technique

Comment: I don't see how it could work. On my side It returns the (expected) message `CallbackSetToNone: The callback was set to None. This may have been unintentional e.g. btn.when_pressed = pressed() instead of btn.when_pressed = pressed`

Comment: Great explanation. I missed such a clear example in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a parameter to a callback function.
You need separate functions for each callback.

Comment: Ok, more good things to learn, thanks. But in the working code above aren't I passing a parameter to the callback function?

Comment: @T.M. Well NO. The lambda creates a new function which retains the calling scope. You are actually still creating separate functions. lambdas are an advanced topic, and not appropriate in a beginner program. By all means read about lambdas, but you need a lot of other knowledge tu understand them.

Comment: `You cannot pass a parameter to a callback function.` That's not correct. See [when.pressed doc](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_pressed)